# How to numerically integrate with unknown coefficients?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerical-value, integral-equations

will it be possible that I could integrate the equations like the following with unknown parameters M and h? I find it really hard. Any advice will be really appreciated, thanks.

```
ff[n_, c_?NumericQ, M_?NumericQ] := 
     NIntegrate[((-2 + Cos[M*c]^2 - 
         Cos[M*c]*Cosh[n + a^2]) Sinh[(n + a^2)])/(1 + 
         Cosh[(n + a^2)])^3, {a, 0, 10}]
    eta[n_] := Sin[M*h]/(Cos[M*h] + Cosh[n])
    NIntegrate[
     ff[b, c,M]*(1 + Cos[M*c]*Cosh[b])/(Cos[M*c] + Cosh[b])^2, {b, -5, 
      5}, {c, 0, h + eta[b]}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. When you integrate something numerically as in `NIntegrate`, you need to provide numeric limits; and, by definitions, these are known. In your case `b` and `M` don't have values yet.

Comment: Hi, Syed, thanks for the comments. My M does not have values yet, I need the integration to be a function of h and M, I know that normally, I should provide values for M and h, but in this case i can't

Comment: Have you tried `Integrate` already?

Comment: yes, doesn't work

Comment: There is no `;` in your code. Is the last line starts from `eta[n_]` or from `NIntegrate` ?

Comment: How about numerically-integrating the expression for a set of (h,M) and then computing an interpolating function for the results.  You can use one of several functions:  InterpolatingFunction, InterpolatingPolynomial, Fit, FindFit, FindFormula.

Comment: Hi, Alex it from NIntegrate

Comment: Hi Josh. thanks for your advice, I am okay with numerically integrating the expressions. I am going to try these functions.

Comment: Hi Josh, I have already googled these functions. Unfortunately, these functions are not applicable to my case. my h and M only have a very weak relationship. these two parameters could be any positive numbers. i cannot decide what number (h,M) I should use. thanks for your advise.

Comment: @Yufei could you, please, update the OP to include this useful piece of information, i.e that $h$ and $M$ are positive numbers? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not entirely satisfactory. Rather, it is intended to illustrate a possible approach that can be used at least in part. The central idea is to use `ParametricNDSolve` at least once and possibly multiple times.

The first stage is easy and seems to work well (i.e., evaluate quickly and without complaints):

```
integrand1 = ((-2 + Cos[M*c]^2 - Cos[M*c] * Cosh[n + a^2]) * Sinh[(n + a^2)]) /
               (1 + Cosh[(n + a^2)])^3;

ff[n_, c_, M_] = g[n, c, M][10] /.
  ParametricNDSolve[
    {g'[a] == integrand1, g[0] == 0},
    g,
    {a, 0, 10},
    {n, c, M}
  ];
```

The next stage is more interesting, more complicated, and ultimately less satisfying. The upper boundary of the second dimension in the multiple integral depends on the first dimension. To accommodate this, I have broken the integral into two one-dimensional integrals, using `ParametricNDSolve` twice. In the first part, I have embedded a parameter in the upper bound. (I didn't know you could do this until I tried.)

```
integrand2 = ff[n, c, M]*(1 + Cos[M*c]*Cosh[n])/(Cos[M*c] + Cosh[n])^2;

vv[n_, M_, h_] = g[n, M, h][h + Sin[h M]/(Cos[h M] + Cosh[n])] /.     
  ParametricNDSolve[
    {g'[c] == integrand2, g[0] == 0},
    g,
    {c, 0, h + Sin[h M]/(Cos[h M] + Cosh[n])},
    {n, M, h}
  ];
```

Here is the second part (of the second stage):

```
final[M_, h_] = g[M, h][5] /. 
  ParametricNDSolve[
    {g'[n] == vv[n, M, h], g[-5] == 0},
    g,
    {n, -5, 5},
    {M, h}
  ];
```

For small values of M and h, the final function evaluates quickly and without complaint. For larger values can take a very long time and produce a number of error messages. I don't have a good sense as to the accuracy of the results.

I leave it to my betters to decide if this approach has any merit at all.